# Адаптивные изображения

Tags: адаптивная-верстка, изображения, вёрстка

День добрый.
Есть слайдер с 10 img. Все изображения "альбомноориентированные" (ширина больше высоты). Необходимо, чтобы изображения пропорционально растягивались по ширине и высоте окна браузера (на весь экран).
Проблема в том, что при портретной ориентации экрана (мобильный, планшет) альбомная картинка сильно искажается - сжимается по ширине и вытягивается по высоте.
Не могу понять как заставить её тянуться по высоте - по ширине пусть она будет больше размера экрана.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить изображениям такие стили

```
img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: /*тут ширина картинки в пикселяx*/;
    height: auto;
   }
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Добавил только @media only screen для различных разрешений экрана под разные девайсы